# emacs: remapping C-[ (currently ESC)

Tags: emacs, remap

I'm using emacs 23 on ubuntu 10.04.  I would like to remap the "C-[" binding.  Currently, when I press it, it gives me "ESC".  Is there a way to remap it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442003/linux-remap-ctrl-key?noredirect=1 which was migrated to SU: http://superuser.com/questions/173851/linux-remap-ctrl-key

Comment: Are you doing this in a terminal or in the native X11 interface?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Emacs binding, but has global effect in X and it's used as handier substitute for ESC for people practicing touch typing. I guess you'll have to modify the X keymap if you want to use it in another fashion, but I wouldn't advice that.

Answer (score 0):

`C-[` ***is*** the ASCII ESCAPE character, which Emacs usually writes as `ESC`.

There is no key involved here (it's a character), and there is no key binding involved here. Or rather, your keyboard's <kbd>Escape</kbd> key sends the control character ESCAPE (also written `C-[` and `ESC`).